# Detect network cable unplugged errors with epoll

Tags: linux, network-programming, epoll

I have tested `epoll` in case of network cable unplugged:

- server opens port 3000
- create epoll and add `server_fd` into epoll
- accept client (client use `telnet`) and add `client_fd` into epoll
- send data to client
- after unplugging cable, `epoll_wait` does not get any event related to `client_fd` forever

I want to detect the error in this situation. Is there any additional solution? Does application need to implement heartbeat method to self-detect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here:

- Implement application-layer heartbeats. In other words, you write code that detects idle connections and periodically sends an application-layer message to essentially probe the connection and make sure that it's still open
- You use TCP keepalive. This basically shifts the work of implementing and dealing with heartbeat messages down to the TCP layer. This seems like a good choice in your case.

To enable and configure TCP keepalive, you need to change the `client_fd` socket options with `setsockopts(2)`. There are 3 parameters you need to check / change:

- `TCP_KEEPCNT` - this is the number of outstanding, unanswered probes that are allowed at any given time. If more than `TCP_KEEPCNT` probes are sent with no reply within a given time interval, the connection is assumed to be dead.
- `TCP_KEEPIDLE` - the amount of time the connection needs to be idle before probing packets start being sent.
- `TCP_KEEPINTVL` - the time between individual probes.

So, you do something like this on `client_fd`:

```
int tcp_keepcnt = 3;
int tcp_keepidle = 30;
int tcp_keepintvl = 60;

setsockopt(client_fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, &tcp_keepcnt, sizeof(tcp_keepcnt));
setsockopt(client_fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &tcp_keepidle, sizeof(tcp_keepidle));
setsockopt(client_fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, &tcp_keepintvl, sizeof(tcp_keepintvl));
```

Broken connections are reported as readable by `epoll(7)`, with the `EPOLLHUP` flag. Note that an order shutdown will be reported as readable *without* `EPOLLHUP`, but instead `read(2)` will return 0.

Keep in mind that detecting a dead connection is not immediate. It will take a while. For example, with the above parameters, it will take roughly 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Telnet servers use TCP keepalive; indeed that's what it was really invented for.

You could send an inoccuous Telnet command every so often.

Both of these ultimately cause `ECONNRESET`.

Comment: What do you mean? I didn't use telnet in server side. I have also create an client application to replace telnet but I get the same result.